# Android Pausing activity on Back and Menu Keys

Tags: android, onkeydown

In my application I have only one activity and I am using `ViewAnimator` for changing the screen. For the Menu and Back Keys I am trying to pause the activity (like home key does) and show a menu or go back to previous `View`.

Angry Birds do the same think (Angry Birds Rio do exactly the same thing what I want).

I have also checked the `OnKeyDown` event to find out how the Home key work but I think it is handled by the system.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onKeyDown%28int%2Candroid.view.KeyEvent%29

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to catch the menu key:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //return true to show some menu
    //return false to not show any menu
}
```

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)

Ir order to catch the back key event:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //do your stuff and Return true to prevent this event from being propagated further
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyUp(int, android.view.KeyEvent)

EDIT: 
Pausing your application's logic is up to you. But you can show an `AlertDialog` with up to three buttons and/or any View you want: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Comment: yes, I know the `onKeyUp` event but how can I pause the the activity or should I handle the every item as paused such as pausing the animations and disabling the unnecessary buttons.

Comment: Pausing your application's logic is up to you. But you can show an AlertDialog with up to three buttons and/or any View you want:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Comment: you can use onBackPressed() after API 5.

Comment: onCreateOptionsMenu is only called once, you should use onPrepareOptionsMenu or onMenuOpened instead to handle this

Comment: @pandre thanks for your answer and comments. I think `AlertDialog` is the correct think for me.

Comment: ok, I will edit my answer adding the reference to `AlertDialog`

Answer (score 0):

you can't override the home key in case the user wants to exit the app if it freezes or something. it would be the only way for them to leave. But home key pauses the activity e.g. in the middle of the an animation press home key and switch to app again the animation continue where you pressed the home key.

Answer (score 0):

The home key will never be trapped by an applications event handlers directly, there is way to detect that it happened with a little work see [onUserLeaveHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29) for the main idea and then onUserInteraction to try and determine if it's the home key.

Not sure exactly what your intent is and I am a little unclear if that's all you want answered.

Anyway dependent on your application you might need to combine this with some other state management, but for a very simple applications it works most of the time.  I only use it for analytic's but it might work for you, I'll just through it out in case it does

```
long userInteractionTime = 0;

@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    userInteractionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    super.onUserInteraction();
}

@Override
public void onUserLeaveHint() {
    long uiDelta = (System.currentTimeMillis() - userInteractionTime);

    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    Log.i("bThere","Last User Interaction = "+uiLag);
    if (uiDelta < 100)
        Log.i("appname","Home Key Pressed");    
    else
        Log.i("appname","Leaving activity for some other reason!");  
}
```

Comment: I don't want to override Home key I want to override Back and Menu keys. that is all.

Comment: Fair enough, you might want to change your title to exclude home keys then and instead say "Back Key" you also say "I have also checked the OnKeyDown event to find out how the Home key work but I think it is handled by the system"

Answer (score 0):

When I get your question correctly you don't want to change the behavior of the home button, right?

To handle the back and menuKey you can use the onKeyDown callback like this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        //DO STUFF
        return true;
    }
            //else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
            //       //DO OTHER STUFF
            //       return false; // I think it's better to use the onMenuOpenCallback
            //       for that...
            //}

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

For the menu button you could also use the onKeyDown callback but I think it's not the best way, since you want to show a menu anyway.
You can use the onMenuOpend callback for that instead (although you should check the docs when this method is called exactly):

```
    @Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
          //DO STUFF
          return true;
    }
```

Hope this helps...
jpm

Comment: ups..didn't see pandres answer...
still, it's a little different :)